# Is there a way of configuring 2 or more web domains for only 1 DNS server?

Tags: server, apache2, dns, bind

I´m now creating 2 websites on Apache2 web server (Ubuntu 20.04 based) and they both have different domains (domain1.com and domain2.com for this example). Webpages are hosted on /var/www/domain1 and /var/www/domain2 and virtual hosts are also created and enabled on /etc/apache2/sites-enabled, having this configurations:

Domain1 virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@domain1
    ServerName domain1
    ServerAlias www.domain1
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain1
    ErrorLog $(APACHE_LOG_DIR)/error.log
    CustomLog $(APACHE_LOG_DIR)/error.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Domain2 virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@domain2
    ServerName domain2
    ServerAlias www.domain2
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain2
    ErrorLog $(APACHE_LOG_DIR)/error.log
    CustomLog $(APACHE_LOG_DIR)/error.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I have already changed in the domain provider the DNS A registry for both domains to my static public IP address but it´s the server DNS configuration what I´m messing with. How would the configuration be for bind9 in order that both domains answer external requests having only one DNS configured on my server side?

Comment: In your DNS server(s), you have to define multiple (in your case: two) "zones" in your `/etc/bind/named.conf.local` file and define the details in the relevant `/etc/bind/db.domain1` and `/etc/bind/db.domain1` zone files.

Comment: You shouldn’t need to do this at all. A single Apache server can handle millions of different domains going to different directories without messing with bind. So long as the `A` or `CNAME` records are correctly set on your DNS records at the domain registrar, you’re good 

Comment: @matigo I am guessing that the OP is managing the DNS server(s) of his domains himself. Normally, domain registrars do not provide DNS management for free; they just point to the DNS server(s) for the domain (together with the "glue records").

Comment: So I have to configure 2 direct resolution zones (one for each domain) and 1 reverse zone?

Comment: Reverse record should be defined by the IP provider.

Comment: Is your bind server the **authoritative** name server for both domains? If not, bind has nothing to do with DNS resolution for those domains.

Comment: @JohnHanley I think so, is there a way to check it out? If I nslookup the domain names, the public IP answers, has it something to do with it?

Comment: Your domain's registrar defines which name servers are authoritative for your domain. Go to your registrar's console and look up which name servers are defined. Note: I recommend a crash course on this stuff. Small mistakes can be hard to debug and can take a long time to get fixed. You can easily trash your domain that will take days to correct due to global caching of DNS resource records.

Comment: It seems to work only locally somehow, so it seems like it is not pointing to the DNS it should. @JohnHanrey